# freebsd compile is so complicated?

Tags: freebsd, bsd

I want to add custom syscall to freebsd(school work). I google hundreds of time. there is no right solution for it.
my homework is: "Add custom syscall to freebsd kernel and recompile the kernel and use it".
finally I find that I should follow instructions in these two pages:

1 : http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/bsd/2003/10/09/adding_system_calls.html

then

2: https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/kernelconfig-building.html

will it shows errors in compile time:

```
<sys/parma.h> no such file or directory
<sys/kern.h> no such file or directory
<sys/syscallargs.h> no such file or directory
```

I removed these three header include form my file then recompile it. now shows other errors like: MAXCPU undeclered in pcpu.h file.

what I missed? how can I do my school work?

NOTE: I use freebsd8 in vbox

Comment: Maybe you should try with the version of FreeBSD from 2003-10-09 as it is the date when that article was written.

Answer (score 2):

Look at what the error messages say; the files don't exist.

- The first include file is a typo; it's `param.h`, not `parma.h`!
- There is no `kern.h`. Maybe you mean `sys/kernel.h`?
- Idem for `syscallargs.h`. Do you perhaps mean `syscall.h`?

You can find header files with e.g:

```
find /usr/src/sys/ -type f -name '*.h'|grep 'sys/.*kern.*\.h'
/usr/src/sys/ofed/include/linux/kernel.h
/usr/src/sys/dev/netmap/netmap_kern.h
...
```

**Update**: More important is determining which includes you *actually need*.

FreeBSD has pretty good documentation. If you want to use a kernel function or data-structure, it is probably covered in section 9 of the manual pages.

You can list all the manual pages in that section with `ls /usr/share/man/man9/ | less`. Or you can use the `apropos` command.
Since you want to implement a syscall, start with e.g.

```
apropos syscall
```

It will return:

```
SYSCALL_MODULE(9)        - syscall kernel module declaration macro
syscall(2), __syscall(2) - indirect system call
```

It seems to me that the first one could be relevant to your assignment. (The second one is how to call a system call from user space.) So read it with `man SYSCALL_MODULE`. Or read it [online](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=SYSCALL_MODULE&sektion=9).

Note that:

```
     A minimal example for a syscall module can be found in
     /usr/share/examples/kld/syscall/module/syscall.c.
```

That example should be enough to get you started on writing your own system call module...

Comment: ya, first two are my typo. 3rd is what refered in tutodial. after all I change as your guide but now: all 3 file (param.h, kernel.h, syscall.h) no such file or directory. same error

Comment: The file `syscallargs.h` exists in the OpenBSD kernel, which is different from the FreeBSD kernel! Concerning the "no such file" errors, please edit your question to show how you are compiling your code.

Comment: @NaserHamidi Have a look at the example mentioned in my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well take a look at share/examples/kld/syscall for a complete implementation as a module.

Adding a new file to teh kernel is left as an exercise for the reader.

Here is a hint: find the newest added file within kern/* subdir AND CHECK WHAT COMMITS WERE DONE TO MAKE IT COMPILE.

In fact you could have done exactly the same with syscall: FIND THE NEWEST ADDED SYSCALL AND CHECK HOW IT WAS ACHIEVED.

All this is available in svn/git repository history.